# What should I display when the user commit an action?

Tags: notification, alerts, push-notification

I'm trying to develop JavaFx application. I'm a beginner in UX and I'm confused between what I need to do for notify the user that the operation are commited correctly.

I have a form that contains the information of an employee when the user writes the information and clicks `Save`. He then receives a [push notification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=occdZWprRjg).

I'm confused if I should display a [push notification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=occdZWprRjg)  or an [alert](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)  or any of these?

Answer (score 1):

This answer depends heavily on many different contextual variables. I recommend you to edit your question. Be more descriptive and specific and try to show us somethings in a mockup and you will get the best answer.

### You should also ask yourselves if sending this notification is necessary. Test it and see if users expect it to be there or if they miss it when it is gone.

However, if I was in your shoes and developing on Android, I would use a toast.

Use the JavaFx equivalent to a toast.

[JavaFX notification](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#notifications).